# Почему мне при вызове функции, помимо функции выводит None?(декораторы, python)

Tags: python, функции, python-3.6, декоратор

```
def answer(func):
    def validator(*args):
        print(f'Результат функции: {func(*args)}')
    return validator
@answer
def a_plus_b(a, b):
    return a + b
print(a_plus_b(3, 5))
print(a_plus_b(7, 9))
```

**Вывод:**

Результат функции: 8

None

Результат функции: 16

None

Comment: Потому что ваш декоратор `validator` не возвращает ничего, и вы печатаете это самое ничего